# Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line

Tags: websocket, sip

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://server-ip:port-name/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Invalid status line on tsip_transport.js?svn=241:359
```

While trying to connect to PBX server on
http://server-ip/call.htm on my server same to which is present on official site below
 https://www.doubango.org/sipml5/call.htm

I get the above error.

The code which gives me the error is

```
var s_url = tsk_string_is_null_or_empty(o_self.o_stack.network.s_websocket_server_url) ?
         tsk_string_format("{0}://{1}:{2}",o_self.s_protocol, o_self.s_host, o_self.i_port) : o_self.o_stack.network.s_websocket_server_url;
tsk_utils_log_info("Connecting to '"+s_url+"'");
o_self.o_ws = new WebSocket(s_url, 'sip');
```

I am getting an error on this line
o_self.o_ws = new WebSocket(s_url, 'sip');

Answer (score 3):

A WebSocket client expects that a WebSocket server returns **101** as the HTTP status code (see [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) for details). Check what HTTP status code your WebSocket server returns. It will give you a hint.